# For a production RequireJS app, is it better to load all scripts merged into one file or separately?

Tags: javascript, optimization, requirejs, data-synchronization

I'm in in the middle of a massive rewrite of our ecommerce system using requirejs & knockback.

Was wondering if anyone else has experience with a production app using requirejs that has a lot of modules/scripts being loaded.

In your experience is it more optimal to use the optimizer to merge all scripts into one file, or to leverage requirejs' ability to load them separately?

I guess the benefit of not merging them seems to be that only the needed scripts get loaded on each page. However, loading each script independently puts more strain on the server, and does not work very well on computers will slow internet connections.

Any advice is appreciated!